# SQL strip text and convert to integer

Tags: sql, text, strip

In my database (SQL 2005) I have a field which holds a comment but in the comment I have an id and I would like to strip out just the id, and IF possible convert it to an int:

`activation successful of id 1010101`

The line above is the exact structure of the data in the db field.

And no I don't want to do this in the code of the application, I actually don't want to touch it, just in case you were wondering ;-)

Comment: You want to change the field in the db to only have the id number and make the field an int?
Kind of unclear of what you're doing.

Comment: On select I would like to just have the number (strip it from the data in the field), I do not want to change the DB field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', column), 999)
FROM table
```

Based on your sample data, this that there is only one occurence of an integer in the string and that it is at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Test table, you will probably use some query  
DECLARE @testTable TABLE(comment VARCHAR(255))  
INSERT INTO @testTable(comment)  
    VALUES ('activation successful of id 1010101')

-- Use Charindex to find "id " then isolate the numeric part  
-- Finally check to make sure the number is numeric before converting  
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(JUSTNUMBER)=1 THEN CAST(JUSTNUMBER AS INTEGER) ELSE -1 END  
FROM (  
       select right(comment, len(comment) - charindex('id ', comment)-2) as justnumber  
       from @testtable) TT
```

I would also add that this approach is more set based and hence more efficient for a bunch of data values.  But it is super easy to do it just for one value as a variable.  Instead of using the column comment you can use a variable like `@chvComment`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a means to test it at the moment, but:

```
select convert(int, substring(fieldName, len('activation successful of id '), len(fieldName) - len('activation successful of id '))) from tableName
```

Answer (score 0):

If the comment string is EXACTLY like that you can use replace.

```
select   replace(comment_col, 'activation successful of id ', '') as id from ....
```

It almost certainly won't be though - what about unsuccessful Activations?
You might end up with nested replace statements

```
select   replace(replace(comment_col, 'activation not successful of id ', ''), 'activation successful of id ', '') as id from ....
```

[sorry can't tell from this edit screen if that's entirely valid sql]

That starts to get messy; you might consider creating a function and putting the replace statements in that.

If this is a one off job, it won't really matter. You could also use a regex, but that's quite slow (and in any case mean you now have 2 problems).

Answer (score 0):

Would you be open to writing a bit of code?  One option, create a CLR User Defined function, then use Regex.  You can find more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx).  This will handle complex strings.

If your above line is always formatted as 'activation successful of id #######', with your number at the end of the field, then:

```
declare @myColumn varchar(100)
set @myColumn = 'activation successful of id 1010102'


SELECT
    @myColumn as [OriginalColumn]
,   CONVERT(int, REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@myColumn), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@myColumn))))) as [DesiredColumn]
```

Will give you:

```
OriginalColumn                           DesiredColumn
---------------------------------------- -------------
activation successful of id 1010102      1010102

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CAST(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@Test),CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@Test))-1)) AS INTEGER)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast(right(column_name,charindex(' ',reverse(column_name))) as int)
```